# backgrid throwing TypeError

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I'm getting this error on line 1620 of backgrid:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of null
```

Here's my code, which imitates the example:

```
var ConversionTag = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var ConversionTagCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ConversionTag,
    url: '/api/tags/conversion',
    parse: function(response, options) {
        return response.conversionTags;
    }
});

var tags = new ConversionTagCollection();

var init = function(parentSelector) {
    var columns = [
        { name: 'chanId', label: 'Channel', cell: 'integer' },
        { name: 'name', label: 'Description', cell: 'string' },
        { name: 'pageUrl', label: 'Conversion URL', cell: 'string' },
        { name: 'secureFl', label: 'Secure Tag', cell: 'integer' },
        { name: 'id', label: 'ID', cell: 'integer', editable: false }
    ];
    var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
        columns: columns,
        collection: tags
    });
    var foo = grid.render().$el; // ERROR!
    $(parentSelector).append(foo);
    tags.fetch();
    window.ctags = tags;
    window.cgrid = grid;
};
```

The error happens on the `foo=` line and  `tags.fetch` never gets called.

Comment: You really shouldn't tag things solely with a tag that only has 1 follower.

Comment: It's a backgrid-specific question, but I'm fine adding backbone as well.

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? And what happens if you change your `secureFl` column label to plain text e.g.: Secure Tag

Comment: @nemesv version 1.7.1

Comment: @nemesv the secureFl thing doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to inject HTML into the header. $.text() calls `document.createTextNode` under the hood and it doesn't accept HTML. You'll have to subclass Header declare its usage explicitly [in your column definition](http://wyuenho.github.com/backgrid/#api-header).

Comment: Changing the secureFl column to `{ name: 'secureFl', label: 'Secure Tag', cell: 'integer' },` didn't fix the issue.

Comment: See if you can still reproduce this on 0.2.0.